# @PropertySource with absolute path to avoid "java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource"

Tags: spring, spring-annotations

My application gets the location of a properties file from an environment variable, and it may not be in the WEB-INF folder.  I'm getting file not found, but this file definitely exists already.  I don't want to use the `classpath:` prefix, and I don't want it to be relative to the app root.

```
@PropertySource("${propfile}")
public class ... {
```

Answer (score 19):

To use an absolute path, try `file:` at the beginning.

```
@PropertySource("file:${propfile}")
```

source: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/PropertySource.html